# How can I include an additional resource in a native image built with Quarkus?

Tags: quarkus

I have a project that contains a file `extra-config.properties` in `src/main/resources` which I reference in my code using:

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("extra-config.properties"))
```

This works perfectly in JVM mode, but when I build a native image the file is not accessible, because it is not included in the binary.

How can I instruct Quarkus to include it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When building a native binary, GraalVM does not include classpath resources in the image by default. Instead you need to specify `-H:IncludeResources` as mentioned [here](https://github.com/oracle/graal/blob/master/substratevm/RESOURCES.md).

The way to do that in Quarkus is to configure the `quarkus-maven-plugin` plugin to add the `additionalBuildArgs` property.
The configuration would look something like the following:

```
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
                    <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${quarkus.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>native-image</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <additionalBuildArgs>-H:IncludeResources=extra-properties.json</additionalBuildArgs>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
```